# my ticket out of fashion -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

From the movie [The Sacrament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sacrament_%282013_film%29):

> — How is it going, man?
>   — Patrick: Man, I got some amazing pictures so far, dude. I can make a whole book out of this. Look at these faces, man.
>   — Jesus.
>   — You know, I can make something really cool out of this and it'd be great for me, 'cause then I could set up a show with Milt when I get back.
>   — Can I see 'em?
>   — Oh, no, that's what **my ticket out of fashion** looks like. What have you guys been up to?
>   — Well, we talked to a bunch of the locals.

What does that really mean?

Comment: @StoneyB - If there was a hat for leaving a comment that should be an answer, that hat would be in your inventory, thanks to your comment here. Call the milliner ;^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick earns his living as a fashion photographer; these photos will provide an avenue to more artistic work.

The expression goes back to the early 19th century when paroled prisoners in the UK got a literal [*ticket of leave*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_of_leave) which entitled them to leave prison - a ***ticket out of*** jail.